# Material-ui TextField dom element how to customize

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I tried below code and while I was expecting to get a yellowish Hi, I got `[object Object]` instead.

Is there a way to fix it? maybe using `InputProps` helps but unfortunately I couldn't find any detailed tutorial about it.

```
<TextField
    id="outlined-multiline-static"
    label="Multiline"
    multiline
    fullWidth
    rows="22"
    value={<div> Hi <div style={{ color: "yellow" }}>There</div></div>}
    variant="outlined"
  />
```

Edit:
I just simplified the problem and don't want the whole of the text to be yellow.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bush-gfi9m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: you want the entire field to be yellow?

Comment: No, I just simplifed the problem. sorry I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: yes, I edit the question. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **inputComponent** inside `InputProps` to achieve customized text field inside the `TextField`

```
InputProps={{
  inputComponent: () => (
    <div style={{ color: "yellow" }}>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
  )
}}
```

[image]

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit funny-curran-yw54t]

Comment: It destroys rows="22" style.

Comment: The reason why it's not multiline is that you customized that field with `div`, and the inner value is not controlled by any state. And you may want to use `input` instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do use div's inside **value** attribute. You want the text to be styled, use InputProps

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        id="outlined-multiline-static"
        fullWidth
        rows="12"
        value="Hi"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{
          style: {
            color: "yellow"
          }
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think it just make whole of the text yellow. sorry I forgot to mention I simplified the problem and don't want whole of the text to be same color please check edit part

Comment: Did not get this edit part. Can you be a more specific

Comment: lets assume the value is <div>Hi <div style={{color:'yellow'}}>there</div></div>

Comment: I mean what if we want to show {black}Hi + {yellow}there.

Comment: Codesandbox also edited to this text, sorry for my mistake.