# How to change text color in TextField?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks, tsx

How can I change the text color in the `value` in `TextField` to red?

I have tried help I found on the internet, but it doesn't work, I am thinking that maybe it is because I am using Typescript, I am new to Typescript.

- Any help is appreciated!

---

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

<TextField label="Date" value={object.date} fullWidth />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016202/react-how-to-conditionally-override-textfield-error-color-in-material-ui/61025884#61025884

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739138/material-ui-textfield-dom-element-how-to-customize/60739370#60739370

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material-ui TextField dom element how to customize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739138/material-ui-textfield-dom-element-how-to-customize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color property in the style of the input component.

```
<TextField inputProps={{ style: { color: "red" } }} />
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But I get this warning: Line 37:7:  'styles' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Comment: @lo7 Not sure what that is unfortunately. I don't use eslint.